# How to loop through an array of objects, that's within another array of objects - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

My data looks something like this:

```
var songs = [
    {Object1: [{Obj1: songId}]},
    {Object2: [{Obj1: songId}]}
];
```

What's the best way to grab all the songId from the entire songs array?

Comment: hacky and slow way with minimal coding: `JSON.stringify(songs).match(/songIdRegex/)` - will give you array of ids

Comment: You can also nest `forEach` or `map` calls on the arrays you want to iterate through

Comment: right your own functions to do it with.... or import the underscore library and use theirs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var songsIdCollection = [];

songs.forEach(function(wrappedSongData) {
    //{ Object1: [ {Obj1: songId} ] }
    wrappedSongData.forEach(function(songIdMaps) {
        //[ {Obj1: songId} ]
        songIdMaps.forEach(function(songIdMap) {
            //{Obj1: songId}
            songsIdCollection.push(songIdMap.Obj1);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Some iteration will do.

```js
var songs = [
        { Object1: [{ Obj1: 8 }] },
        { Object2: [{ Obj1: 99 }] }
    ],
    songId = [];

songs.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
        o[k].forEach(function (a) {
            songId.push(a.Obj1);
        });
    });
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(songId, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```